# How can I connect to Mongodb Atlas

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I am trying to connect to MongoDB atlas from node.js but I keep getting an error. I have whitelisted my ip address in database access and also allowed all ips but the issue keeps on persisting. Also for the record, I have counterchecked and my password as well as username are all correct. Could someone help me out?
here is my database connection code

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const connectDB = (url) => {
  console.info(`Trying to connect to ${url}...`);
  try {
    mongoose.connect(url, {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
     
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
module.exports = connectDB;
```

and here is my uri

```js
DATABASE_URI =mongodb+srv://pepela:1034Vgsu@cluster0.h7ofj.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm beginner, but I can show u how I connected my atlas, I  will use your data.

First I've created file named "config.js" :

```
module.exports = {
  databaseUri: "mongodb+srv://pepela:1034Vgsu@cluster0.h7ofj.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority",
}
```

Then in file where i connecting my MongoDB i called it server.js i have something like this

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

//im getting my MongoDB connection link from config.js file
const {databaseUri} = require("./config");

// and then the connection function 
mongoose.connect(databaseUri, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
})
  .then(() => {
    console.log('MongoDB Connected')
  })
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Purpose of having these databaseUri in separate file is for protection, when I'm pushing my code to GitHub I add it to .gitignore file